# CSS Columns Responsive Issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We are building a simple website in CSS to provide educational resources for other students here at my school. I have chosen to go with the Bootstrap Columns. The problem is on our school's desktop computers and tablets stacks the columns into different rows, instead of just shrinking the size down.

Here is all of the relevant HTML code:

```
<!-- Left Side Bar -->
    <div style="background-color:#F3F8FC;" class="col-lg-2 mobile-hide" ><!-- Not Displayed on Mobile -->
        <div class="fotd">
            <div class="fotd-title">
                <h4>Fact Of The Day</h4>
            </div>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="twitter mobile-hide">
            <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/RHL_Inspire" data-widget-id="720721136867282945">Tweets by @RHL_Inspire</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Center Content -->
    <div class="col-lg-7 ">
        <h3 class="content title">Letter from The Editor In Narwhal</h3>
        <p class="content" >
        This is a link. <a href="/math">This is the actual link</a>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lobortis,     
        </p>
    </div>



<!-- Right Side -->
    <div style="background-color:#F3F8FC;" class="col-lg-3 mobile-hide">
       <h3 class ="center mobile-hide">Editors Picks!</h3>
            <ul class="stickynote mobile-hide">
                <li class="stickynote mobile-hide">
                    <a class="stickynote" href="http://www.google.com">
                        Google
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="stickynote">
                    <a class="stickynote" href="http://www.google.com">
                        Google
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="stickynote">
                    <a class="stickynote" href="http://www.google.com">
                        Google
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="stickynote">
                    <a class="stickynote" href="http://www.google.com">
                        Google
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="stickynote">
                    <a class="stickynote" href="http://www.google.com">
                        Google
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="stickynote">
                    <a class="stickynote" href="http://www.google.com">
                        Google
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <footer>&copy; 2016 The StickyNote | <a href="http://www.google.ca">Google</a></footer>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please create a Jsfiddle and post it so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are having trouble with. Could you try creating an example as @geeksal suggested, or elaborate more? The only thing I see is that the tweets move to the far left when the screen goes to `lg`.

Comment: The HTML is malformed. Don't put H3 inside P and there are too many closing DIV tags. Please clean this up so we can help.

Comment: Sorry for the poor quality of my question and the messy code; its worked on by several Grade 6 ans 8 students. Il clean it up and add some more details. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that we had to change the code to specify two sizes of the column. For example in the original code we had:

```
 <div style="background-color:#F3F8FC;" class="col-lg-7">
```

This had to be simply changed to:

```
<div style="background-color:#F3F8FC;" class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7">
```

The `col-sm-7` gets used for smaller screens(such as Tablets and the lower-res desktop computers.